# segmentation fault when trying to start rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rvm

I was running "rails server" on the console when my internet connection was interrupted.

When I tried to run rails, I got a segmentation fault.

When I executed

> rails server

or

> rails dbconsole

I got **/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault**

I commented out sqlite from my Gemfile, then started up rails server successfully and then stopped it. I then uncommented sqlite and started rails server. Everything seems to be OK now.

Can anyone explain what happened? Should I be concerned about this. What should I do if this happens again?

I'm running ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.5

Comment: Looks more like you're running Ruby 2.0.0-p247.

Comment: did you installed the native library for sqlite?

Comment: Dave: Good eye! I hadn't noticed that 2.0.0-p247 reference in the gem path. I don't know-I'm clearly not using Ruby 2.0. Could that be the problem? Somehow the wrong gem got installed

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to happen because your environment is not configured properly, you write that you use `ruby 1.8.7` but he error comes from `ruby-2.0.0-p247`, such things happen when your shell initialization files reset/reconfigure `PATH` after RVM was loaded. To fix it one time run:

```
rvm use 1.8.7 --install
```

To fix it long term run:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

and make sure to read all the outputs, RVM will give you warnings if things can be fixed automatically.

After the problem is fixed install gems for application:

```
bundle install
```

and try running application again:

```
rails s
```

Additionally to the misconfiguration I would advice you update your ruby because it is very old ruby that is no more supported and will not get security updates, so instead of the first command use:

```
rvm get stable
rvm use ruby --install --default --ruby-version
```

RVM resolves the name `ruby` to latest known version of ruby, `--install` will tell it to install the ruby if missing, `--default` will set this ruby as default and `--ruby-version` will generate `.ruby-version` file which loads the selected ruby when changing directories to the application folder (with `cd`).

Comment: yeah looks like it's loading a gem that was compiled against a different version of ruby, hence the segfault when it tries to load it...

Answer (score -3):

Ruby 1.8.7 is no more supported and will not get any security updates, you should update ASAP:

```
rvm use --install 2.0.0
```

Install application gems:

```
bundle install
```

And start rails again:

```
rails s
```

Comment: someone would care explaining why downvoted - I would like to avoid giving bad advice again

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question (though it may be good advice).

Comment: this kind of question does not have good answer, you would need to dig for long time and you would end up with the information - ruby was not used properly and you would need to use that steps to fix it

Comment: Hey mpapis. I can't explain why people downvoted you. But I can explain why your answer is an unhelpful type of answer. It's a total subject change.  When someone is running old unsupported software--there could be a host of reasons. A good answer will first take the persons question seriously and perhaps as a side note suggest an upgrade. And, ultimately, if the question does "not have a good answer", then what are you doing answering it? If the question does "have a good answer", then I'm all ears!